# Windows 10 Swift Pair (BLE)

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

At the moment, I am developing an Android-based BLE peripheral and I'm hoping to integrate Windows 10 Swift Pair, following this documentation: [Microsoft Swift Pair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/bluetooth-swift-pair)

I have ensured that my Windows version is above 1803 and have ensured that the "Show notifications to connect using Swift Pair" box is checked.

I followed the [payload structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0dhe.png) defined in the documentation.

I double confirmed the BLE advertise data by using an Android Test App and a [Windows Test App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKeUi.png) (On the same PC I'm getting this to work). I'm sure that I'm advertising the correct payload.

Unfortunately, the notification of swift pairing did not pop up and I'm at loss at what I'm missing. It will be great if anyone could tell me what's wrong!

---

**Updates 17 Dec 2020**

The notifications are showing now. The only change I made was to increase the txpower of the Advertisement.

Currently, I'm facing another issue. Pairing doesn't work on all PC. I tested with 2 PC (that's every PC in my inventory). 1 work and 1 doesn't.

**Working PC**: BLE 5.0 (LMP 9.256) |
**Not Working PC**: BLE 5.1 (LMP 10.256)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your BT radio on PC supports HCI_VS_MSFT_Read_Supported_Features commands?

Comment: Pardon me for my lack of understanding. How can I check if PC supports HCI_VS_MSFT_Read_Supported_Features commands?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/microsoft-defined-bluetooth-hci-commands-and-events

Comment: The notifications are showing now. The only change I made was to increase the txpower of the Advertisement.